# How to know (without unscrewing the casing) if my laptop is capable of supporting Solid State Drives (SSDs)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata

I have a lenovo V470 and as an Xmas treat I am thinking about upgrading to Solid State Drive (SSD) to utilise the benifit. However, I don't know if my laptop's motherboard is capable of supporting SSDs.

What I did so far is to go to crucial and scan my system. However, I think crucial's SSDs may not be financially ideal choice and there could be cheaper options. Nevertheless, it still doesn't confirm how to understand whether my laptop supports SSDs at all.

Could someone please provide some suggestion? My understanding is that it if a laptop supports SATA II or SATA III then it should also support SSD.

**IF APPROPRIATE**  I would also like to know the ramifications for cloning my existing hard drive (as opposed to the safest method - reinstalling everything).

Kind Regards,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Form_factors

Comment: If you buy any Samsung SSD then it comes with "Samsung Data Migration" which handles migrating your Windows install (and all other files) from the existing HDD to the new SSD. You can also download it from http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No laptop available to the general public these days supports proprietary drive interfaces. Since SSDs are available in almost every public interface, and certainly every public storage interface, your system can support one or more SSDs.

Comment: I was hoping for this! Kind regards,

Comment: @hagubear: Do note that you'll need to read the manual to find out which storage interfaces your machine supports.

Comment: I did a crucial scan again and it says that it can support SATA III

Comment: Then you should be able to use any SATA SSD.

Comment: The same is trus if it supported SATA I or SATA II (or even SAS). SATA is backwards compatible. The only thing you really need to be careful with is the drive thickness. Which is about 9mm for almost any drive, though there are a few rare exceptions. (Both thicker and thinner).